# What is the doLookup method's purpose?

Tags: java, oop, object, methods

[This is where I found it as a method.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#doLookup-java.lang.String-)

I'm trying to write a  program that allows the user to look-up objects. Is the LookUp() method, in java, useful if I want the user to be able to type in an object ID? Once the user typed in the right ID, the whole object would be printed to the screen, not just the ID.

Comment: If you want a dictionary of objects by their ID, use a java.util.Map. JNDI is overkill.

Comment: @JBNizet They have dictionaries in java? That's interesting. I didn't know that. What is JNDI?

Comment: JNDI is the Java Naming and Directory Interface API. It's an API used to register and lookup services in Java EE servers, for example, or to access an LDAP server.

Comment: See [The JNDI Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/)